# MYSQL: GET DISTINCT $col1 with highest $col2

Tags: php, mysql

my table lools like this:

```
name    | var
----------------
Joe     | 3
Liz     | 1
Liz     | 4
Joe     | 2
Peter   | 3
Joe     | 7
Liz     | 2
```

I am looking for a MYSQL query that will give me the DISCTINCT names of column `name` with the highest `var` related to the `name`.
So, for the example above, I am looking for

```
Joe   | 7
Liz   | 4
Peter | 3
```

my try was:

```
SELECT name, var 
FROM table
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY var DESC
```

I tried, too,

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, var
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name), var
```

but with those I got distinct combinations of name,var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the aggregate function `MAX()` to get what you want with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT name, MAX(var) as var
FROM table
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name ASC
```

... the `ORDER BY` clause is optional in this case.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
select name, max(var) as maxvar from Table1
group by name
ORDER BY maxvar DESC
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3eb9e2/4)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT NAME, MAX(VAR) as var FROM XYZ GROUP BY NAME
```

--- Example:
you have `SELECT NAME, VAR FROM XYZ`

```
Name  |  var
Mustafa  6
Tim      4
Tim      7
Joey     3
Tim      5
Joey     8
Mustafa  12
```

Now after using the Grouping function you will get the following, which is a result of the GROUP BY function. It does not take care about the other columns and its values. So you might have some random numbers here.

```
SELECT NAME, VAR FROM XYZ GROUP BY NAME

Name  |  var
Tim      5
Joey     3
Mustafa  12     <-- only this record ok?!
```

---- Now we use `MAX()` for our "var" field. so it always searches for all the records within our groups for the MAX() value. If you would like to, you could add an Order statement for the MAX() Value. ( `ORDER BY MAX(VAR)` )

```
SELECT NAME, MAX(VAR) as var FROM XYZ GROUP BY NAME

Name  |  var
Tim      7
Joey     8
Mustafa  12
```

Comment: You don't need `DISTINCT` when you use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Can you add some explanation to this answer? Code-only answers are generally discouraged.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman added more details. :) Hope it's a bit better now.